# Teechart for Android (Mono): Pie chart not displayed

Tags: android, xamarin.android, teechart

I've been playing with the demo of TeeChart for Android (Mono) for a while, but I have been unable to get the Pie charts to display.  Everytime I run the demo with a pie chart I see a screen with no pie chart, but the legend contains a valid list of the points added.

Do pie charts not work with the beta?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options here:

1. You have marks visible and they don't leave room for the pie circle/ellipse to be painted. Try disabling them:

   `pie1.Marks.Visible = false;`
2. Your device/emulator screen is small or normal, see [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), and *ZoomStyles.InChart* is not supported in smaller screens. You could try setting up an emulator with large screen to experiment with that. You could also try setting *Zoom.Style* to *FullChart*:

   `tChart1.Zoom.Style = Steema.TeeChart.ZoomStyles.FullChart;`
3. Does the Pie2D.cs example in MonodroidTabDemo shipped with the beta package work for you? If so, you could use that example as a guide for your Pie charts.

If the problem persists we would need more detailed information about the device or emulator you are using and a simple code snippet we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem. You can send us files via http://www.steema.net/upload/.